# (reactjs) how to set a promise or set the current state into local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-storage

I'm trying to build a very simple app for searching articles and using the localstorage to display more info about each article but when I set to save into the session storage for some reason is saving the initial or previous state, I assume because I need to set async for this but I just can't figure how

This is how I have it right now, findArticleQuery() is called on the handleSubmit

```
 useEffect(
      () =>{
          findArticlesQuery();
      } ,[]
  ) 
  const findArticlesQuery = (query) => {   //search function
    axios.get(`url`)
    .then(res => {                
      [res.data].map((val) =>(        
        setState(val)         
      ))                                     
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response)
    });        
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    findArticlesQuery(e.target.search.value)
    sessionStorage.setItem('localData', JSON.stringify(state))   //<--here I get the value of the previous state          
    e.target.search.value = '';       
  }
```

I need to use the session storage because I will have a detailed article component page.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Why do you want to use session storage? State should do the job

Comment: Set State has a callback, which is only called once set state has completed its work.  You could try putting the session storage call there.  E.g. something like, but I haven't tested...  setState(val, sessionStorage.setItem('localData', JSON.stringify(state))  )

Comment: You don't need session/local Storage unless you are caching or sharing it between multiple components.

Comment: @ChrisAdams OP is using hooks, so setState is unlikely to have a callback.

Comment: the funny thing is that if I hit submit twice, it gets the correct value @chrisAdams

Comment: Probably because by the time of the second submit, the first set state has completed.  @cuspyMd also has a reasonable looking solution.   Re kobe 's point, I haven't checked, but I don't see why using hooks means setState doesn't have the call back.  This isn't strictly for 'old-style' coding using callbacks etc.  but I have tended to use this for console logging to check my state has been updated and I can dump out latest state.

Answer (score 1):

You can get search result from `findArticlesQuery()` like below.

```
...
  const findArticlesQuery = (query) => {   //search function
    return axios.get(`url`)
    .then(res => {                        
      setState(res.data)
      return res.data
    })   
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    findArticlesQuery(e.target.search.value)
       .then(val => sessionStorage.setItem('localData', JSON.stringify(val)))
    e.target.search.value = '';       
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For saving state in the localStorage with React Hooks, something I've been using and that is extremely convenient is [useLocalStorage](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/).

Disclaimer : I am not the creator of this lib.